# Question Regarding the Conceptual Significance of Dual Space

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that a dual space is the vector space generated by the set of linear maps to some field. What I don't grasp is why this is significant, or what is different between a field and any other mapping, like from a vector space V to W. Are there real world examples of using the properties of dual spaces to solve a problem, like in engineering? Thanks.

Comment: In differential geometry the dual space of tangent spaces is used to define differential forms, which are very important in many contexts, e.g. in general relativity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form

Comment: Given a basis of a vector space and any basis vector, the mapping from an arbitrary vector to the coefficient of the vector with that basis vector wrt to the given basis is a member of the dual space.

Comment: You might find my [video](https://youtu.be/eOIJzb7SItg) helpful.

Comment: In terms of matrices, duality amounts to **transposition** (some people will object that my definition is not intrinsic, but for a first intuitive grasp, it must be said). For example, a linear map considered in a certain basis is a **line vector** operating by matrix multiplication on column vectors to yield a number.

Comment: @JeanMarie We call that a *row vector*.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin You are right ; thanks. Erroneous "transfer" from french to english...